# Wrapping div around sortlist

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

The following image is the effect that I am going to implement. I used jquery ui sortlist so that the items within the box can be dragged and sorted. However, I cannot wrap a div around the sortlist. Actually I have come across the same problems whenever I using bootstrap columns. I cannot easily wrap div around the content, and format the inside elements if columns are used.

[image]

Here it is my HTML code:

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8 col-md-8 col-lg-8">
    <div class="summary-theme">
        <p>Theme1</p>
        <ul id="sortable1" class="connectedSortable">
            <li class="ui-state-default">Item 1</li>
            <li class="ui-state-default">Item 2</li>
            <li class="ui-state-default">Item 3</li>
            <li class="ui-state-default">Item 4</li>
            <li class="ui-state-default">Item 5</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:
/*** SUMMARY BOXES ***/

```
.summary-theme{
  display:block;
  margin-top:10px;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  width:100%;
  background: #fff;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px #A7A7A7;
}
.summary-theme .connectedSortable{
  border:0px;
}
.summary-theme p{
  display:block;
  float:left;
  margin:-20px -15px;
  background: #0CBD94;
  border: 4px solid #FFFFFF;
}
```

The box can wrap successfully if I set the overflow to be 'hidden'. But in that case, the tag `<p>` will not show properly because it is negative margins. 
Things look alright when they are not wrap by Bootstrap Columns. Sorry I don't know how to write an online demo with Bootstrap features. So do you have any ideas how to fix the div wrap problem?

Thank you!

Comment: Show a picture of how it ends up looking?

Comment: OP says she doesn't know how to set up a demo with Bootstrap features. Just a moment, I'll make a JSFiddle.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/DanielApt/RG45s/ Here's a JSFiddle showing I guess what OP is experiencing.

Comment: I don't know what issues you are having, but **always** make sure that any column is contained by a `.row` and subsequently contained by `.container` or `.container-fluid`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where `overflow: hidden` can't be used, the next option is to go for a common clearfix, such as:

```
.summary-theme:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
```

I'm not familiar with BS, but it might already have a class for this that you can just reuse.

Comment: Great! It works! I will check more about clearfix. Thank you!!